# Structure an xreg parameter with three dynamic regressors in Arima

Tags: r, dynamic, time-series, regression

Thanks for viewing my question.....

I am working with the following file:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1a6y2ak4qkcix0/xregs1.csv

This code reads in the csv file

> ads1 <- read.table(csvfile, header=TRUE, sep = ",")
>
> ts1 <- ts(ads1, start=c(2012,1), frequency=49)
>
> ts1 <- ts(ads1[,4:5], start=c(2012,1), frequency=49)

The ts1 object allows me to choose either Units or Sales as the time series variable in an Arima function.
Since this is a Dynamic Regression model, I'm attempting to follow Professor Hyndman's suggestion in a previous post to use a format like:

> xreg <- cbind(Weekday=model.matrix(~as.factor(modelfitsample$Weekday)), 
>                         Day=modelfitsample$Day,
>                     Christmas=modelfitsample$Christmas)

I am attempting to use WK_PRICE as a continuous regressor and two sets of dummy variables for seasonality and promotional events in the creation of a matrix that will be used in the xreg parameter (i.e., wk_2:wk_49 for weekly seasonality and wk_p_2:wk_p_49 for promotional events).

I'm struggling to correctly set up the xreg parameter following the example above.

Thanks for your time and attention.

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you are asking:

```
ads1 <- ts(ads1, start=c(2012,1),frequency=49)
qty <- ads1[,4]
sls <- ads1[,5]
price <- ads1[,6]
week <- ads1[,7:54]
promo <- ts(rowSums(ads1[,55:ncol(ads1)]), start=c(2012,1), frequency=49)

library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(qty, xreg=cbind(price,promo,week))
```

Note that you do not want to have a separate promo variable for every type of week (essentially modelling the promo*week interaction). So I have collapsed this to a single dummy variable indicating if each week involved a promotion or not.

I would not recommend modelling weekly seasonality with dummy variables as it will take far too many degrees of freedom. A much better solution is to use Fourier terms, like this:

```
fw <- fourier(qty, K=3)
fit3 <- auto.arima(qty, xreg=cbind(price,promo,fw))
```

Using K=3 Fourier terms gave the smallest AICc value.

Comment: K factor in Fourier can be any value ? Here K =3, How it is possible to decide the apt K value?

Comment: Read the last line. You minimize the AICc.